# Extracting sub images of an image without repetitions using MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Given an image `A`, I want to subdivide it into blocks of a given size (let's say for example subimages of dimension `3-by-3`) and remove repeated blocks. (Similar to what `unique` does to vectors, but for blocks.)
I did try to use a loop as follows:

```
function [ Ref_M ] = Sub_Div_f( M,C_W )
%UNTITLED Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
Sub_I=0;
Ref_M=0;
[L_M H_M ]=size(M); %deffine the size of d IMG
for i=1:C_W:L_M

    for j=1:C_W:H_M
        [L_Ref_M H_Ref_M ]=size(Ref_M);
        Sub_I=M(i:i+C_W-1,j:j+C_W-1);% Subimage
        if (i==1 && j==1)
           Ref_M=Sub_I;
        else
            nn=0;
            for k=1:C_W:H_Ref_M
                if ( Sub_I == Ref_M(1:C_W,k:k+C_W-1 ))
                    break;
                else
                    nn=nn+1;
                    if (nn==(H_Ref_M/C_W))
                       Ref_M(1:C_W, H_Ref_M+1:H_Ref_M+C_W)=Sub_I;
                    end
                end
            end       

        end
    end
end
```

But that takes a lot of time. Can I use `unique` to get that? Like: `S = unique(A,'3,3')` or something. Or does `unique` work for single pixels only? If not using `unique`, is there are any function that can do that?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. What is `:S=unique(A,'3,3')` supposed to express?

Comment: its just an expresion, where A it the image, and 3x3 is the sub-image( the number of pixels that it should process over instad of one pixel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First reshape all blocks of size `blockSize=[3,3]` to rows.

You can do this either using `im2col` if you have the image processing toolbox installed.

```
im2row = @(A,blockSize) im2col(A,blockSize,'distinct').';
```

or if you don't, you can use:

```
im2row = @(A,blockSize) ...
         reshape(permute(reshape(A, blockSize(1), size(A,1)/blockSize(1),...
                                    blockSize(2), size(A,2)/blockSize(2)),...
                         [2,4,1,3]),...
                 [], prod(blockSize));
```

Then we use `unique(.,'rows')` to filter out the unique blocks:

```
uniqueBlocks = unique(im2row(A,blockSize), 'rows');
```

You will then need to transpose and reshape the values back again to their block form:

```
reshape(uniqueBlocks.',blockSize(1),blockSize(2),[])
```

Comment: i used reshape(uniqueBlocks.',blockSize,[],1) .

thank you soo much. that was soo helpful.